# Junit testing a void response method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a void method namely invokeEllaAsync that I would like to test in the Spring eco-system and provided below. The method also calls another void method from inside as a nested call.

The mocking information is provided below,

```
   @InjectMocks
    private EllaService ellaService;

    private IrisBo validIrisBo;

    @Mock
    private EllaRequestDto ellaRequestDtoMock;

    @Mock
    private EntityServiceConnectable<EllaResponseDto> connectorMock;

    @Mock
    private EllaResponseDto ellaResponseMock;


    @Async
    public void invokeEllaAsync( final IrisBo irisBo ) throws EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException {

        try {
            callEllaService( irisBo );
        }

        /**
         * Asynchronously call Ella. Determine if traffic is applicable for Ella and if yes forward to Ella.
         *
         * @param irisEo
         * @return List<ResultBo>
         * @throws EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException
         */

        catch( EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException ex ) {
            throw new EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException( ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause() );
        }
    }

    private void callEllaService( final IrisBo irisBo ) throws EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException {

        HttpHeaders elladHeaders = createRequestHeaders( irisBo );

        ServiceResponse<EllaResponseDto> response = connector.call( EllaDtoConverter.convertToRequest( irisBo ), elladHeaders );

        if( !response.isSuccess() ) {
            throw new EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException( response.getErrorMessage(), response.getException().getCause() );
        }

    }
```

I try to test the `invokeEllaAsync` method as follows,

```
    @Test
    public void testInvokeEllaShowsSuccess() {

        ServiceResponse<EllaResponseDto> validServiceResponseMock = mock( ServiceResponse.class );

        when( connectorMock.call( any(), (HttpHeaders) any() ) ).thenReturn( validServiceResponseMock );
        when( validServiceResponseMock.isSuccess() ).thenReturn( true );

        ellaService.invokeEllaAsync( validIrisBo );
        verify( ellaService, times( 1 ) ).invokeEllaAsync( validIrisBo );
    }
```

I get the error provided below,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type EllaService and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
```

If I understand it correctly, the `ellaService` is the type of `@InjectMocks` and not the `@Mock`. Hence, the test is not executed.

How do I write the test correctly?

Comment: No, `ellaService` is of type `EllaService`. `@InjectMocks` means you inject your mocks into it. It does not make it a mock. Also it is the thing you are testing, so you don't want it to be a mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can verify only mocked components (Annotated with @ Mock).
EllaService is not a moc, but instance of real class from your code. @ InjectMock annotation just set private fields of EllaService with mocks.

Generally when test void method you need to ensure that some mocked components were called with expected parameters, so you need to verify not ellaService call, but call to mocked components that is used in invokeEllaAsync method.

Comment: Would you please kindly check the test I added an answer?

Answer (score 1):

After I read the answer, I added this test in the codebase.

```
@Test
public void testInvokeEllaAsyncSuccessfullyCallsCallEllaService() {

    ellaService.invokeEllaAsync( validIrisBo );

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic( EllaDtoConverter.class, VerificationModeFactory.times( 1 ) );
    EllaDtoConverter.convertToRequest( validIrisBo );

    verify( connectorMock, times( 1 ) ).call( any(), (HttpHeaders) any() );
}
```

Comment: You should add this in your original post, not in a response, it might get deleted by an admin

Comment: @Arefe looks great. As I remember you can use any(HttpHeaders.class)

Comment: @alexey28 I tried and not working. I updated the test with `PowerMock` for a static method. While I am partially aware that testing the `static` methods are not great, it's a converter and I will need that.

Comment: Is this an answer or does the code belong to the question?

Comment: This is an answer. I learned from the answer by @alexey28 and  produced it later on.